# Describing GAM from ggplot's stat_smooth in a paper

Tags: generalized-additive-model, ggplot2

I am writing a paper where I have some figures with lines drawn using `ggplot2`'s `stat_smooth` with no arguments. When I generate a plot I get a warning saying that it is being fit with a GAM with formula `y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"))`.

What I am wondering is: In writing a paper, how should I describe how this line was generated?

From the plotting output I've guessed that it is a "generalized additive model with cubic splines as a basis function". I don't really understand GAMs so I don't know if this is a comprehensible way to describe the model. The details of this model are not important for the paper; I am just using `stat_smooth` to draw a line in a figure and want to give it an informative caption.

Comment: The references in the help (`?gam:::s`) describe these objects (*smoothing splines*) in some detail. See also the references in `?smooth.spline`. Wikipedia gives a brief overview [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing_spline), with some of the same references/readings.